# Loading elasticsearch index data to pyspark rdd : error

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark

I am trying to load elasticsearch index data to pyspark rdd using following code,

Version: elasticsearch: 2.3.4
         spark: 2.0
         elasticsearch-hadoop (jar): 2.3.4

running pyspark:

```
bin\pyspark --master local[2] --jars jars\elasticsearch-hadoop-2.3.4.jar
```

[image]

Getting index data:

```
es_read_conf = {"es.resource" : "index/type"}

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf= es_read_conf)
```

Code is running but returning empty rdd with following msg,

```
16/08/30 20:42:20 WARN EsInputFormat: Cannot determine task id...
```

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: With the latest version of elasticsearch 2.4.0, it worked. But here problem is only document id s are returned with empty dictionary(indexed content is not returned). any suggestion?